# Execution order for Code obfuscation

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, gulp

I am trying to obfuscate my JS code using gulp utility. [Ionic Application]

```
gulp.task('ng_annotate_app',function (done) {
      gulp.src(['!www/js/toaster.min.js','www/js/*.js','www/common/*.js'])
        .pipe(strip())
          .pipe(stripDebug())
          .pipe(rename({
              suffix: ".min",
              extname: ".js"
          }))
          .pipe(uglify({mangle: false}))
          .pipe(ngAnnotate({single_quotes: true}))
          .(obfuscate())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('www/dist'))
      .on('end', done);
    });
```

I have my angular module starter in file a.js and factory in b.js like below.
a.js :

```
var mod=angular.module ...
```

b.js

```
mod.factory ...
```

var mod above in a.js in getting obfuscated to some dummy string but in b.js it is unchanged.Hence my application shows error and am unable to run.

Help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, do not use variables from one file to another. Instead of using `mod.factory`, you can use `angular.module('<Your module name>').factory`.

Or you may group relevant files in another module e.g. `angular.module('<another module name>',[]).factory` and then include this module in the dependencies of main module file (app.js mostly) `angular.module('myApp', ['<another module name>'])`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am able to invoke now by declaring and making use of same variable in app.js but in $httpProvider.defaults.headers.delete here headers is obfuscated and hence delete fails resulting in undefined error.

Comment: Any idea on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem..you need to use a tool that ensures it looks at all the submitted files and maintains the same names on all files, not breaking any dependencies. [Jscrambler](https://jscrambler.com/en/) guarantees that and worked for me.